# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting when using datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I am having a problem with my Python 2.7 Program. It gives me an error: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
I would very much like to know what is wrong with my program.

```
    from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

print '&s/%s/%s %s:%s:%s' % (now.month, now.day, now.year, now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
```

PostScript - I know of the possible duplicates but they do not adress the same question and the answers provided do not work.

Comment: You have a typo, a `&s` instead of a `%s`.

Comment: Tip for the future: one crucial debugging skill is finding a minimal case.  `print` by itself works; your command doesn't; so you should have tried to remove things from your `print` statement until you isolated exactly where the error was.

Answer (score 0):

You have an `&` at the start instead of a `%` , this causes the string to only have 5 placeholder formats, but you are supplying it 6 values to replace, causing the error. (As `'&s'` is not a place holder) , you need to use `%s` instead.

Also, this is not necessary as you can directly use `datetime.strftime()` method to format the date in the required format -

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

print now.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```